# Passing Data to Windows Console Control Handler

Tags: c++, windows, console, controls, handler

I am working on writing a simple game engine and I am having trouble handling Windows console events; specifically, I cannot figure out how to pass custom data to the callback handler.

I first call this code to specify my callback function:

```c
SetConsoleCtrlHandler((PHANDLER_ROUTINE)WindowsSystemManager::ConsoleControlHandler, true);
```

My static-member callback function is defined as:

```c
bool WINAPI WindowsSystemManager::ConsoleControlHandler(DWORD controlType){
    if(controlType == CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT){
        MessageBox(NULL, L"Close Event Captured", L"Close Event Captured", NULL);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Everything works fine - when I click on the close button in the console, this MessageBox pops up. Only problem is, I need to call code that flushes a logging buffer to a log file on this type of shutdown (as well as other clean-up), and the Logger instance is a member in my WindowsSystemManager.

I have dealt with a similar problem of passing custom data to window handles by using SetWindowLongPtr and GetWindowLongPtr successfully, but I can't find any information on how to do this type of thing with console control handlers. Any thoughts?

EDIT: I got this functionality working based on MSalters' suggestions. The final code for the console control handler is here:

```c
bool WINAPI WindowsSystemManager::ConsoleControlHandler(DWORD controlType){
    BerserkEngine* engine = (BerserkEngine*)GetWindowLongPtr(GetConsoleWindow(), GWLP_USERDATA);
    if(controlType == CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT){
        engine->~BerserkEngine();
        PostQuitMessage(0);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Where I set this custom data pointer in the WindowsSystemManager constructor:

```c
SetWindowLongPtr(GetConsoleWindow(), GWL_USERDATA, (LONG_PTR)this->engine);
```

Comment: Did you used this function to catch the CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT from anywhere in your program ? Please Refer the Question I am following right now http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40464545/custom-event-listener-in-c?noredirect=1#comment68199812_40464545

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why you'd need this. You can have multiple windows, but only one console.

However, `GetConsoleWindow` will give you the console `HWND`, on which you might call `SetWindowLongPtr`. Not very clean (you're not supposed to do this on windows that you don't manage), but it might just work.

Comment: Perhaps I wasn't clear enough - there's only one console, and only one window. All I need to be able to do is access the Logger instance from within my console control handler. The method you outlined should work, as I was unaware you could retrieve the console window's handle. But what do you mean by that I shouldn't do it on windows I don't manage?

Comment: Since there's only one console, you'll likely have only a single Logger. Make it a singleton instead, then you don't have to pass it. As for `SetWindowLongPtr`, you only have `sizeof(LONG_PTR)` bytes available for `GWLP_USERDATA`, and those bytes are reserved for the window class creator (i.e. CSRSS).

Comment: Hmm, I'll look into making it a singleton, that'd make a lot more sense. However, as of right now everything works - I'll look into the CSRSS though! Thanks

Comment: _"on which you might call SetWindowLongPtr"_ >> I'm afraid that's not true. You cannot call `SetWindowLongPtr` on a console HWND. The reason is that the window procedure resides in another process (CRSS in Vista and before, conhost.exe in Win7 / Win2k8SP2 and higher)

Comment: @Abel: `SetWindowLongPtr` doesn't use the window procedure. It affects the window memory. The documentation states that it's fine to call it for windows of another process, provided that's at the same UIPI level.

Comment: Hmm... For changing memory of another process, you should use `WriteProcessMemory`. For changing a window-attr, use `SetWindowLongPtr`. Reading this thread again, I see it is about `GWL_USERDATA`. My comment was about `GWL_WNDPROC`, and that will give you an _"Access denied"_, both for pre/post Win7 systems, because the window is owned by CSRSS/Conhost. As you say, it must be the same UIPI. I cannot test on Vista, but it's a fact that CSRSS runs **at a different privilege level**. Setting user data works in Win7, but I doubt it works on systems with CSRSS, because of the higher UIPI.