# Custom Event Listener in C++

Tags: c++, winapi

In a command line application which is single threaded, I want to know when user closes (by clicking on red cross on top right) shutdowns PC or Logoff without logging out of my application first, so that I can clear the cookies that I am storing in window's registry.

Is there any way I can know when user has done the events mentioned above and call a function within my application or call a separate EXE or a Batch file following the event ?

I need this functionality because I want to prevent a possible scenario where in Registry is full of unwanted thrash created by not logging out of application properly.

Since my application runs over command prompt like`C:\Users\admin\Desktop>Application.exe -task "ConnectServer" --ip 127.0.0.1` I am looking out for some way to either manage cookies in efficient way or to delete the cookies after catching the events mentioned above.

Comment: There's the [standard signals](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/SIG_types) to begin with, although windows won't generate them.

Comment: @StoryTeller "although windows won't generate them" Could you please explain this? It works fine for me when I register my signalhandler(s) with the `signal` function.

Comment: @SimonKraemer, the [msdn documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xdkz3x12.aspx) mentions *"The SIGILL and SIGTERM signals are not generated under Windows"*

Comment: @StoryTeller Thank you for clarifying. I don't really have this use case so this didn't occur to me yet. The programs I work on are used as windows services mostly - listening to SIGINT and SIGABRT is sufficient.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but - the Windows registry (" a database of configuration settings") is _not_ the place for storing values whose lifetimes are limited to the lifetime of the process. If you want these "cookies" to be discarded whenever your app exits, why not just store them in variables? (If your answer is that some other process needs access to them, I would suggest IPC techniques such as named pipes.)

Comment: As Gavin said, this is not the place to store such information. It's precisely this kind of behaviour that causes windows to become sluggish and lethargic over time. Use the temp folder which is for oddly enough, temporary stuff. What happens if you cop a power-loss event? Extra crap added to the registry? No, just no.

Comment: Can you suggest any other approach for this, and how can i use environment  variables that persist for single command-prompt only so that my session gets maintained automatically @GavinLock  ? I tries it using a batch file i generate from my application and execute within but for the parent cmd process it gets vanished when my process ends.

Comment: @DevMac - I meant C++ variables (as opposed to environment variables) - but to provide suggestions, we'll need some more info on the problem itself. Something like: "I am writing a set of command line tools that xxx and yyy. The tools all need a 12-digit number to connect to a server. The number is generated when the....", or "I am writing a C++ app that lanches other apllications and needs to pass them a..." or whatever

Comment: Okay, I am writing a C++ Application that connects to server on ssl and uses REST API for request and response. I am handling these request and response handling from my code, for login I need to pass the username password and ip and in turn i get a session id from server, then for further communication i need to send that sesison id back to server for it to validate the legitimate user along with the request stream i.e GET, PUT, POST. I need to store this session id for further communication. @GavinLock

Comment: @DevMac - If this is all being done in one app, which starts, logs in, does some get\put\post actions and then exits when completely finished, then the session ID would just be stored in a C++ variable. If the app needs to be run more than once within the same session, please elaborate.

Comment: A cleaner solution would be to store the data in a private file, and setting the [FILE_FLAG_DELETE_ON_CLOSE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858.aspx) flag. Irrespective of how your process is terminated, the OS will make sure to clean up the file.

Comment: That's what exactly the problem you guessed @GavinLock. Th application runs several times, with new parameters and activities each time so storing in variable doesn't justifies here.

Comment: @IInspectable If i store it in a file then how will i maintain session of different or same user on the same machine ?

Comment: @DevMac: The same way you would have done it with the registry. Both registry keys and files in a file system have ACLs, that control access.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`SetConsoleCtrlHandler()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686016(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Apparently can't be used for shutdown and logoff on Windows 7 and up, where you need a hidden window to get these events.

Comment: I have tried to use this but since i don't have any process that is continuously  running, how can i track these events ?

Comment: @DevMac You need a running process to get such events in real time. If you don't want to keep a foreground app running, you will have to write a background service instead. Or, depending on your Windows edition and policy settings, maybe a shutdown script that invokes an app.

Comment: And how will I bind that running process with the cmd that the user will open to use my application ? @RemyLebeau

Comment: @DevMac your app *is* the running process. There is no "binding" involved.